# Nginx not finding PHP files

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos

I've been searching through all the questions asked and all answers haven't worked. I'm trying to install Damn Vulnerable Web App to my Centos 6.9 server, but when I try to access the page, I'm greeted with a 404 File Not Found error. I can access html files perfectly, just not PHP.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}


}
```

Can anyone help at all please?

UPDATE:
After multiple attempts, below are the updated files. Now getting a 'File Not Found' even though the files reside within the root directory stated in the default.conf file.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  localhost;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
   # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

}

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING   $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI   $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

The changes seen in other questions haven't had any positive effect.

THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED.
The location in default.conf was pointing to 'html' where it should have been '/usr/share/nginx/html'.

Comment: What do your error logs say? Do you have PHP installed?

Comment: And do you have the php-fpm service running?

Comment: PHP-fpm service is running and the logs say absolutely nothing:
[10-Apr-2017 16:18:14] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8875
[10-Apr-2017 16:18:14] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: Do a `curl --head <url>` to see what HTTP status you're getting. If it's a PHP issue, you'll get a 5XX. If it's an nginx issue, you'll get a 4XX. (Generally.)

Comment: # curl --head http://192.168.56.11:8080/dvwa/setup.php
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 15:49:42 GMT
Connection: close

Comment: "Apache-Coyote/1.1" -- that's not nginx.

Comment: Your nginx config here is listening on port 80 but you're making a request on port 8080.

Comment: Apologies: 
curl --head http://192.168.56.11:80/dvwa/setup.php
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 16:02:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3

It now says file not found when attempting to access; 192.168.56.11:80/dvwa/setup.php, but the dvwa directory resides within the root directory stated above, with the setup.php file inside that directory

/usr/share/nginx/html/dvwa/setup.php

Comment: Not sure this is your issue, but I always specify my `root` directive with a full absolute path. Not sure offhand what the behavior is for relative paths as in your last location block. I'd move your `root` declaration to the server block and then remove it from all the location blocks.

Comment: I've just tried this too and still returning file not found.

Comment: Just checked my NGINX logs and they now say :      2017/04/10 17:14:21 [error] 9088#9088: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.56.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /dvwa/setup.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.56.11"

Comment: See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/517190/nginx-1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown).

Comment: These have been unsuccessful

Comment: @SwiftBeginner - Sounds like you solved it. If so, you should post your solution as an official "answer" so it is more visible to others. Plus folks can also vote on it (Answering your own question is allowed on S.O. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED. The 'root' in default.conf/location ~ .php$ was pointing to 'html' where it should have been '/usr/share/nginx/html'.